# How to correctly create data filter inside Anypoint Studio's Microsoft Dynamics Nav connector?

Tags: mule-connector

The team is trying to use Microsoft Dynamics Nav connector inside Anypoint Studio 7.3 to get data via a dynamic filter.  However we are getting all data, not the subset we are filtering for

We loaded WSDL file inside Soap UI, got a soap request body like so:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:con="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/contactcard">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <con:ReadMultiple>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <con:filter>
            <con:Field>Name</con:Field>
            <con:Criteria>'John Smith'</con:Criteria>
         </con:filter>
      </con:ReadMultiple>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and confirmed that the filter works by editing the Criteria field.

Since we are still learning Anypoint Studio we decided to stick with the soap xml and created inside our mule flow a variable called "filter" and defined it exactly like the payload above:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
read('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:con="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/contactcard">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <con:ReadMultiple>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <con:filter>
            <con:Field>Name</con:Field>
            <con:Criteria>"John Smith"</con:Criteria>
         </con:filter>
      </con:ReadMultiple>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>','application/xml')
```

We added a logger and confirmed that variable "filter" looks like the code above.

As the last step we configured Microsoft Dynamics Page connector and confirmed that connection was OK.  We defined Service as "Contact Card" and Operation as Read Multiple.

Then we defined Entity by connecting the "filter" key of the "filter" variable(input)[I know, too many filters] to the "filter" element of the output. The output "filter" element got automatically exposed, the input "filter" key of the filter variable got exposed after we defined metadata for the filter variable.  As metadata we used an example XML file with the same content as the "filter" variable.  DataWeave got generated like so:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
ns ns0 urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/contactcard
---
{
    filter :  vars.filter.ns0#ReadMultiple.ns0#filter
}
```

Everything worked but we pulled all the data.  As we edited Criteria from --John Smith- to another non-existing value - we still got all the data.  It is my conviction that the actual filter as defined by data weave is null.

Anybody knows how to define filter correctly?  The Mulesoft docs describing DynamicsNav connector did not mention filter entity.

Any attempt to manually modify generated DataWeave code resulted in all kind of exceptions.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
here is the contents of file used to generate metadata for the filter variable.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:con="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/contactcard">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <con:ReadMultiple>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <con:filter>
            <con:Field>Name</con:Field>
            <con:Criteria>'John Smith'</con:Criteria>
         </con:filter>
      </con:ReadMultiple>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who cares...
This is how you create a Filter entity for Page Operation (Microsoft Dynamics Nav Connector)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
ns ns0 urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/contactcard
---
{
    filter: [{
        ns0#Field : "COMPANY_NAME",
        ns0#Criteria : vars.CompanyName
    }]
}
```

Obviously, for any other entity like "VendorCard" the namespace needs to be edited.  The field  value HAS TO be all upper case.  However, the log will show you all existing valid field names if you do not get it right.  "CompanyName" is a variable that you have to set up elsewhere, "vars" is the gateway to all variables in your mule message.  More filters can be added to the same "filter" array if you need to filter on multiple fields.

I wish Mulesoft docs would walk you through the process.  Oh, well.